# How to clear the background image of a button with code in a C# Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I clear the background image of a button for a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application written in C#? What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
myButton.BackgroundImage = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this will work but I would try putting `Button.BackgroundImage = null` as the last line in the on click listener.